# ! Package keyval Error: hyperref undefined. l.4319 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}?

Tags: hyperref

I know that the question may be too stupid, but I'm trying to compile the TeX file of Calculus Made Easy by Silvanus Thompson available at [this page](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33283) with TeXworks but the compiling always end up with the following line:

```
! Package keyval Error: hyperref undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4319 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}

?
```

And I'm a complete noob at LaTeX and I have no clue of what's going on. I've googled a little but it seems that none of the results I've seen adress the problem I'm having. Yes, I've pressed `H <Return>` but then there's a lot of stuff appearing on the screen and I'm lost again.

Comment: The [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) does not provide a `hyperref` key, which is exactly the use case in your [template](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33283) (lines 209-227). Remove it and try again...

Comment: @Werner Short answer?

Comment: @egreg: Done...

Answer (score 3):

The [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) does not provide a `hyperref` key, which is exactly the use case in your [template](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33283) (lines 209-226):

```
209: \usepackage[pdftex,
210:   hyperref,% <---------------- problem....
211:   hyperfootnotes=false,
212:   pdftitle={The Project Gutenberg eBook \#\ebook: Calculus Made Easy, 2nd Edition},
213:   pdfauthor={Silvanus Phillips Thompson},
214:   pdfkeywords={Paula Appling, Don Bindner, Chris Curnow, Andrew D. Hwang,
               Project Gutenberg Online Distributed Proofreading Team},
215:   pdfstartview=Fit,    % default value
216:   pdfstartpage=1,      % default value
217:   pdfpagemode=UseNone, % default value
218:   bookmarks=true,      % default value
219:   linktocpage=false,   % default value
220:   pdfpagelayout=\PDFPageLayout,
221:   pdfdisplaydoctitle,
222:   pdfpagelabels=true,
223:   bookmarksopen=true,
224:   bookmarksopenlevel=0,
225:   colorlinks=true,
226:   linkcolor=\HLinkColor]{hyperref}[2007/02/07]
```

Remove it and try again...

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue, my textsudio latex code is running smoothly, but this error appears from nowhere,
I am using the line number package, by removing the hyperref from below solved the problem.

\usepackage[running]{lineno,hyperref}\linenumbers